# Node 12.14.1 port problem. Does not take port even after shutting the server down

Tags: node.js, macos, port

Why node version 12.14.1 not leaving the specified port even after shutting the server down  and also its not using the other port if 3000 is not free. I have to manually kill the process on the specified port

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("App listening to port" + port);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "shutting the server down", if not killing the process?

Comment: Additionally – why _would_ it automatically use another port "behind your back"?